# javascript form validation and form action conflict

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to finish a form validation via javascript and also put an action with .py file to execute in the #form# tag.
but the problem is, when after I submit the data, it wont redirect to the .py action. 
so I get rid of the preventdefault(), at this time, .py file is executetd, but the form validation cant work.........

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Student grade registration system</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <header class="masthead">
        <h1>Student grade system</h1>
    </header>
      <section class="main">
          <p>Please fill out this form correctly and click 'save' to save         it. after that, you can click 'results' to see your grade results.
            If there is any concern, please contact your coordinator for details.</p>
          <form name="sgs" action="hello.py" method="post">
            <div class="formbox">
                  <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" autocomplete="off" placeholder="your first name" class="med" />
                  <span id="fnameWarning" class="alert"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="formbox">
                  <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" autocomplete="off" placeholder="your last name" class="med" />
                  <span id="lnameWarning" class="alert"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="formbox">
                  <label for="studentnumber">Student Number</label>
                  <input type="text" name="studentnumber" id="studentnumber" pattern="[0-9]{6}" title="must be a 6-digit number" autocomplete="off" placeholder="your student number" class="med" />
                  <span id="studentnumberWarning" class="alert"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="formbox">
                  <label for="course">Course</label>
                  <select name="course" id="course" class="med">
                    <option value="1" selected>Course</option>
                    <option value="2">CST8260</option>
                    <option value="3">CST8209</option>
                    <option value="4">MAD9013</option>
                    <option value="5">CST8279</option>
                  </select><span id="courseWarning" class="alert"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="formbox">
                  <label for="Work type">Work type</label>
                  <select name="Worktype" id="worktype" class="med">
                    <option value="1" selected>Work type</option>
                    <option value="2">Assignments</option>
                    <option value="3">Midterms</option>
                    <option value="4">Final Exam</option>
                  </select><span id="worktypeWarning" class="alert"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="formbox">
                    <label for="grade">Grade</label>
                    <input type="text" name="grade" id="grade" pattern="[,0-9]{1,}" title="must be a grade between 0 and 100" placeholder="your grade, use commas to seperate them" class="med" />
                    <span id="gradeWarning" class="alert"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="formbox">
              <div class="formbox buttons">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" id="submitbtn" class="btn"/>
              </div>
              <div class="formbox">
            <div class="formbox buttons">
              <a href="display.html">   <input type="button" value="results" class="btn" /></a>
            </div>
          </form>
      </section>
      <footer class="footer">
        <p>&copy; Algonquin college registration office.</p>
      </footer>
  </div>
<script src="scripts/validate.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/events.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the javascript files:

```
function validate(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var valid=true;
    if(sgs.firstname.value === ""){
    document.getElementById('fnameWarning').innerHTML="*Please enter a first name*";
        valid = false;
}
    if(sgs.lastname.value == ""){
        document.getElementById('lnameWarning').innerHTML="*Please enter a last name*";
        valid=false;
}
    if(sgs.studentnumber.value == ""){
        document.getElementById('studentnumberWarning').innerHTML="*Please enter a student number*";
        valid=false;
}
if(sgs.grade.value == ""){
        document.getElementById('gradeWarning').innerHTML="*Please enter a grade*";
        valid=false;
}
if(sgs.course.options.selectedIndex === 0){
        document.getElementById('courseWarning').innerHTML="*Please select a course*";
        valid = false;
}
if(sgs.worktype.options.selectedIndex === 0){
    document.getElementById('worktypeWarning').innerHTML="*Please select a work type*";
    valid = false;
}
if(valid){
    alert("Thank you! please click 'results' to see the results");
}
return valid;
```

};

```
//form element events
document.getElementById("firstname").addEventListener("blur", function(){
    if(this.value !== ""){
    fnameWarning.innerHTML = "";
}
});
document.getElementById("lastname").addEventListener("blur", function(){
if(this.value !== ""){
    lnameWarning.innerHTML = "";
}
});
document.getElementById("studentnumber").addEventListener("blur", function()     
    if(this.value !== ""){
        studentnumberWarning.innerHTML = "";
}
});
document.getElementById("grade").addEventListener("blur", function(){
    if(this.value !== ""){
        gradeWarning.innerHTML = "";
}
});
document.getElementById("course").addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(sgs.course.options.selectedIndex !== 0){
        courseWarning.innerHTML = "";
}
});
document.getElementById("worktype").addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(sgs.worktype.options.selectedIndex !== 0){
        worktypeWarning.innerHTML = "";
}
});

document.sgs.addEventListener("submit", validate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave the `e.preventDefault();` and then use a jQuery Ajax call to send the data to the .py file after you validate the input using:

```
$.post("hello.py", $("form").serializeArray(), function(result) {
    // handle response here
}
```

Comment: no problem! you just need to import the jQuery Javascript file either through a CDN or reference a local file.

Comment: You can download or get a link to the file here: https://code.jquery.com/